# access vba array by looping through recordset

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I have a loop which I want to create an array then use the array to insert into another table.

```
Band     Country 
AIR       FR 
Bon Jovi  US 
Oasis     UK 
Blur      UK 
Green Day US 
Metalica  US
```

I want to loop through this recordset, so I want to create arrays, for example, arrayFR = "AIR"; arrayUK = "Blur vbCrLf Oasis" and arrayUS = "Bon Jovi vbCrLf Green Day vbCrLf Metalica".

At the same time, based on this recordset, I have created a temp table with columns FR, UK & US. I hope to use the arrays created, then insert into the temp table like the view below.

```
FR        UK        US 
AIR       Blur      Bon Jovi 
          Oasis     Green Day 
                    Metalica
```

I don't know how to start with as I have searched a lot of arrays related pages but doesn't help, please help me gurus! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear if your data is already in a table - if not, then it should be before trying to manipulate by populating an array. A table with two columns (Band, Country) populated with the data can be accessed/sorted then placed into arrays.

Comment: HI Wayne, the view above is already in a table and the view below is a temp table created with country columns (MEMO type) FR, UK & US, as column names depends on my recordset.

Comment: part of my codes are:<br>If Not (rs1.EOF And rs1.BOF) Then
rs1.MoveFirst
' LOOPING STARTS
 Do Until rs1.EOF = True
 'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
 'Do something here to create the array
 rs1.MoveNext
 Loop
 ' LOOPING ENDS
 db.TableDefs.Append tbl
 RefreshDatabaseWindow
 'fld.Close
 Set fld = Nothing
 'tbl.Close
 Set tbl = Nothing
Else
 MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

Comment: for my array in loop, I want to have something like those below, array myFriends will store those values from the loop and join together:
Dim strFriends(0 To 6) As String, lngPosition As Long
strFriends(0) = "Alpha"
strFriends(1) = "Bravo"
strFriends(2) = "Charlie"
strFriends(3) = "Delta"
strFriends(4) = "Echo"
strFriends(5) = "Foxtrot"
strFriends(6) = "Golf"
Dim myFriends As String
'This will produce the following string: "Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo, Foxtrot, Golf"
myFriends = Join(strFriends, ", ")
MsgBox myFriends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your end result (per country) is a single field with bands delimited by CRLF, you can make it simple. Add the following Dims;

```
Dim aArray(10, 2) As String
Dim iC      As Integer
Dim i       As Integer
IC = 0
```

Then add this inside your loop (change field names as required):

```
Debug.Print rs1!country & vbTab & rs1!band
If aArray(iC, 1) <> rs1!country Then
    iC = iC + 1
    If iC > 10 Then MsgBox "There are more than 10 countries! Change the code...", vbOKOnly, "Too many countries"
    aArray(iC, 1) = rs1!country
    aArray(iC, 2) = rs1!band
Else
    aArray(iC, 2) = aArray(iC, 2) & vbCrLf & rs1!band
End If
```

To see results:

```
For i = 1 To iC
    MsgBox aArray(i, 1) & vbCrLf & aArray(i, 2)
Next i
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, for "Dim aArray(10, 2) As String", what does it mean?

Comment: It means it is a two dimension array. In this case it contains 10 'rows' with each 'row' containing two 'columns'. In your case, since you already wanted to concatenate Band data with VBCRLF, it is rather simple to have each row contain: Country + list of Bands

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating your temp table by using a simple CrossTab query ? If that suits your needs, it will be much easier.

Comment: I already have one temp table/query for crosstab query. However, there is a "layout issue" according to my superior. Sometimes there will be blank fields on the 1st row of records, like the UK column, it will be blank on 1st row, then Blur in 2nd and Oasis in 3rd. That's why I have to look into VBA for help to make it looks nicer.